# Where exactly namenode is running port 53210 or 50070

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

what is the diference between port 53210 & 50070 in hadoop?
In which port namenode is working either in 53210 or 50070?
If nameNode running on 53210 then why we are accessing namenode information from 50070?

Comment: Which of the configuration file has mention for port 53210?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the namenode doesn't run anything on 53210 by default.

50070 is the web UI and 8020 is the port clients use to communicate with the namenode.
I think 8020 is also used by datanodes to send heartbeat to NameNode, but I'm not 100% certain here.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing for namenode runs on port 53210 by default. 50070 is the default port for Namenode web UI while 8020 is the default IPC port for namenode.

Overidding the default ports in the config files is possible.